# How to "link" already uploaded images to ImageField in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have models like:

```
class Symbol(models.Model): 
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True) #uniqe
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    imgslug = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=255, blank=True) #uniqe

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PlatformImages(models.Model):
    symbol_id  = models.ForeignKey('Symbol', on_delete=models.CASCADE,) 
    platform_id = models.ForeignKey('Platform', on_delete=models.PROTECT,)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['symbol_id', 'symbol_id']),
        ]
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['symbol_id', 'platform_id'], name='unique_symbol_img_per_platform')
        ]

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.platform_id)

    def get_platform_name(self):
        return self.platform_id
```

I have folders per platform in media folder like: media/apple/, media/google/, media/twitter/ ,etc.

Inside each folder there are ~1000-3000 images, named as "imgslug" for almost each Symbol. I had uploaded them in a batch.

And I use it In template to show all available images for symbol per platform:

```
{% for platform in platforms %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_PREFIX }}{{platform}}/{{symbol.imgslug}}" >
    <h2 class="">{{platform|title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that now I need to edit/upload new images via Admin tool.
I added this code to admin.py to edit mapping of image to Platform:

```
class PlatformInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlatformImages

class SymbolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PlatformInline,
    ]
```

Now I think to add **ImageField** to **PlatformImages** Model, but I need:

- to save each image per unique platform for symbol in corresponding
  folder
- to add there already uploaded files

And I don't know how to do it to achieve something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the web, I came to following solution:

1. to save each image per unique platform for symbol in corresponding folder added to models.py:

   ```
   class Platform(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
       folder = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

   def platform_directory_path(instance, filename):
       return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.platform_id.folder, filename)

   class PlatformImages(models.Model):
       symbol_id  = models.ForeignKey('Symbol', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
       platform_id = models.ForeignKey('Platform', on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to=platform_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
   ```

2) to link already uploaded images to ImageField, open shell

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

and execute script:

```
from django.db import models
images = PlatformImages.objects.all()
for image in images:
    platform = image.platform_id.name
    symbol = image.symbol_id.imgslug
    imagePath = str(platform +'/'+symbol)
    print (str(image.id) + " : " + imagePath)
    image.image = imagePath
    image.save()
```

What helped me to find that solution:

[Django docs - upload_to may also be a callable, such as a function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

[How to link already existing image to an ImageField](https://web.archive.org/web/20150607184514/https://andrewbrookins.com/tech/set-the-path-to-an-imagefield-in-django-manually/)